# set two field primary key

Tags: ms-access, primary-key

table1

---

id1  ==> number

id2 ==>  number

---

id want id1 contain uniqe number and id2 contain unique number.

how can set id1 and id2 `primary key`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In the Table Designer, Select both rows, and then click the Primary Key button in the Toolbar.

OR, open the Query Designer, change the view to SQL View, and type the following code:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table_name ADD CONSTRAINT your_pk_name PRIMARY KEY(id1, id2);
```

Then, hit the run button. This will create a Primary key which includes both of those fields.

If you are asking about having an Auto-incrementing integer field in both columns, you can't. You would have to do that programmatically. Access (and most other db's) only allow one "autonumber" field per table.

Comment: This probably isn't best practice, however, since if at any time you want to join data to this table, you would have to define multiple joins, which not only makes your SQL look funky, but also I would imagine slows down performance.  Also, if you are designing your database properly, the user will likely not even see the primary key (unless it represents a meaningful number for them to reference later).  In all my databases, therefore, I keep each table as one field that represents the primary key for that table.

Comment: @William - agreed compsit keys are a bit of a pain, and there is no reason to use one if it can be avoided. However, there are very valid cases, "reference" tables, representing many-to-many relationships being just one. Also, you make the point "unless it represents a meaningful number to them [the user]." I would add that using a PK that has any semantic meaning to the user is just asking for bad news.  All that said, single PK per table is the ideal, until it's not :-)

Comment: There are instances, however, where a PK would be meaningful to the User.  Thinking of the Northwind database as an example, you can have Customers and Orders.  In this scenario, the Orders.ID column is likely a primary key, but would have some meaning to the end user that may want to look up a specific order by Order Number.