# select previous row value for same user (multiple records)

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a query in Access 2010 (have also tried on 2013, same result) that is working but not perfectly for all records. I'm wondering if anyone knows what is causing the error.

Here is the query (adapted from http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html#AnotherRecord):

```
SELECT t_test_table.individ, t_test_table.test_date, t_test_table.score1, (SELECT top 1 Dupe.score1                 
    FROM t_test_table AS Dupe                     
    WHERE Dupe.individ = t_test_table.individ 
      AND Dupe.test_date < t_test_table.test_date  
ORDER BY Dupe.primary DESC, Dupe.individ
) AS PriorValue, [score1]-[priorvalue] AS scorechange
FROM t_test_table;
```

The way the data is set up, an individual has multiple records in the file (designated by individ) representing different dates a test was taken. A date AND individ combination are unique - you can only take a test once. [primary] refers to primary key column. I just made it because the individ field is not a primary key since multiples are possible (I'm not including it here due to space)

The goal of the above code was to create the following:

```
individ test_date   score1  PriorValue  scorechange 
1       3/1/2013    40      
1       6/4/2013    51            40    11
1       7/25/2013   55            51    4
1      12/13/2013   59            55    4
5      8/29/2009    39      
5      12/9/2009    47            39    8
5       6/1/2010    58            47    11
5       8/28/2010   42            58    -16
5      12/15/2010   51            42    9
```

Here is what I actually got. You can see that for individ 1, it winds up taking the first score rather than the previous score for each subsequent record. For individ 5, it kind of works, but the final priorvalue should be 42 and not 58.

```
individ test_date   score1  PriorValue  scorechange 
1       3/1/2012    40      
1       6/4/2012    51            40    11
1       7/25/2012   55            40    15
1      12/13/2012   59            40    19
5      8/29/2005    39      
5      12/9/2005    47            39    8
5       6/1/2006    58            47    11
5       8/28/2006   42            58    -16
5      12/15/2006   51            58    -7
```

Does anyone have any ideas about what went wrong here? In other records, it works perfectly, but I can't determine what is causing some records to fail to take the previous value.Any help is appreciated, and let me know if you require additional information.

Comment: If you want the previous record, why not sort by `test_date desc`?

Comment: Gordon, you're right -- I accepted Isaac's answer below with that suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the most recent test for a given individ, you'll need to include a sort by date. In your inner query, replace

```
ORDER BY Dupe.primary DESC, Dupe.individ
```

with

```
ORDER BY Dupe.test_date DESC
```

It's hard to say exactly what effect sorting by `primary` has, since you haven't told us how you're generating the values of `primary`. If the combination of `individ` and `test_date` is guaranteed to be unique, you might want to consider [making the two of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022332/set-two-field-primary-key) into your primary key instead of creating a new thing. The `Dupe.individ` in the `ORDER BY` line has no effect, since your `WHERE` clause already limited the results of the inner query to one individ.

Comment: This worked. Thanks, Isaac - I really appreciate it. This was exactly the problem. (note to anyone else seeing this answer: Primary was generated by autonumber.)